# Are there relative pronouns in Chinese

Tags: grammar

Are there words for relative pronouns, for example:

The man, **who** was walking to the shop, was tall.

Is there a Chinese word for the bolded "who"?

Comment: thank you. I am copy editing a text written by a native speaker of Chinese in English and noticing how awkward the constructions are that require relational terms. Normally seems to be resolved by repetition of the subject in separate sentences. I have no prior knowledge of Chinese grammar but began to wonder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, when you say "something/someone, who/which has some characters, is abc/is doing xyz.", after translated to Chinese, usually it will be "some characters的something/someone is abc/is doing xyzor separate to two sentence, "something/someone has some character, (optional: 而且/and) is abc/is doing xyz."

In your sample, in addition to @user3919509's answer, you can also say "那个正往店铺走的男子很高". Since "The man" could be anyone, in this case you want to add "該名/那个". **In another case, if everybody knows the man, say, we have his name, it will be little different**. For example, "Tom, who is working in a big company, has two kids", you can say "汤姆在一个大公司工作，有两个小孩。“

Hope this helps.

Comment: So basically Chinese doesn't have them in the sense that English does?

Comment: @KevinSang yes, you are correct.

Comment: Internet points for you

Comment: @kevin similar grammatical structure exists in Japanese as well.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence can be interpret as:

該名步行到店鋪的男子，身材高大

Where `該名` will be 'who' in the sentence